# How to configure socket.io with my express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a back-end right now and am trying to set up socket.io.  I've done this in the past, but am not getting any response with my io.on('connection') right now, and I'm unsure why.  Would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. To my knowledge, this is pretty identical to how they set it up on the socket.io docs.

Ideally, I'd like to separate my socket events into a different folder, instead of having them in app.js or server.js.

My code:

```
// app.js
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();
require('./db/mongo/config')();

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '' : process.env.DEV_URL,
  }),
);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

module.exports = app;
```

```
// server.js

'use strict';

const app = require('../src/app');
const debug = require('debug')('backend:server');
const http = require('http');

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5555');

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io'(server);

// ideally I would like to have this in a socket.js file or somewhere similar
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('socket connection');
});

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);


function normalizePort(val) {
  const port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  const bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}

module.exports = {
  server,
};
```

Comment: Missing a character in this `const io = require('socket.io'(server);` which should be this: `const io = require('socket.io')(server);`

Answer (score 0):

1. socketio.js

```
/**
 * Socket.io configuration
 */

'use strict';


// When the user disconnects.. perform this
function onDisconnect(socket) {
    console.log("Disconnection process$$$$$$$")
    socket.disconnect();
}

// When the user connects.. perform this
function onConnect(socket) {
    // When the client emits 'info', this listens and executes
    socket.on('info', function (data) {
        console.info('[%s] %s', socket.address, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    });



}

module.exports = function (socketio) {
    socketio.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.address = socket.handshake.address !== null ?
            socket.handshake.address.address + ':' + socket.handshake.address.port :
            process.env.DOMAIN;

        socket.connectedAt = new Date();
        // Call onDisconnect.
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log("In Disconnect method*****")
            onDisconnect(socket);
            console.info('[%s] DISCONNECTED', socket.address);
        });


        // Call onConnect.
        onConnect(socket);
        console.info('[%s] CONNECTED', socket.address);
    });
};
```

2.in server.js

```
const app = require('../src/app');
const debug = require('debug')('backend:server');
const http = require('http');

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '5555');

const server = http.createServer(app);
var socketio = require('socket.io')(server);
require('./socketio')(socketio);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);


function normalizePort(val) {
    const port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    const bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;

    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

function onListening() {
    const addr = server.address();
    const bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}

module.exports = {
    server,
};
```